# Polymer 1.0: Data binding variable to <iron-meta> element (value attribute)

Tags: data-binding, polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer 1.0, I am trying to data bind a string variable `{{str}}` to an `<iron-meta>` element (tag in parent element) as follows.

**This fails:**

```
<iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="{{str}}"></iron-meta>
```

The above code breaks. But the following code works (without the binding).

**This works:**

```
<iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="foo/bar"></iron-meta>
```

The difference is the variable version `{{str}}` fails and the constant version `"foo/bar"` works.

**Does anyone have a clue what is what is breaking the binding and how to fix it?**

Edits in response to comment questions:

1. How does it fail? This fails silently. The values I have printed out simply do not update when I press the Login and Register buttons.
2. [Here is a link](https://github.com/veronicawwashington/polymer-sandbox/blob/master/app/elements/my-auth-toolbar/my-auth-toolbar.html) to the code in a Github repository. See lines

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get any errors at all? Where/how is `str` declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an [attribute binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding.html#attribute-binding) and not a property binding

```
<input type="text" value$="{{str}}" />
```

Comment: Both versions of the binding syntax work as expected. Specifically, `value="{{str}}"` AND `value$={{str}}` both work.

Comment: I am confused by the answer, the code has no input element to bind to? Also if assumed epascarello refers to the iron-selector by his example, it actually has a property 'value' (not attribute value), why should you use value$={{..}} to set it?
@Mowzer can you also please further clear what you meant by your comment?