# Polymer 1.0: Does <iron-meta> support binding to dynamic variables?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I can get my `<iron-meta>` instance to work properly when using a static value. But when I bind the value to a dynamic variable (using `{{}}`) it `<iron-meta>` no longer behaves as expected.

Does `<iron-meta>` support binding its value to dynamic variables?

```
<iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="foo/bar"></iron-meta> // works
<iron-meta id="meta" key="info" value="{{str}}"></iron-meta> // fails
```

Previous work

This question is a refinement of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282947/polymer-1-0-data-binding-variable-to-iron-meta-element-value-attribute) in order to clarify that the ONLY thing causing the problem is the change from a static string value to a dynamic string value binding. I was getting a lot of other suggesting that had nothing to do with the change from static to dynamic so I thought it might be best to rewrite the question to clarify that. But the entire code context is contained in the links there if that would help.

Alternative solutions

There has been some recent chatter about using `<iron-localstorage>`. Perhaps that is the best way to go for dynamic binding essentially creating global variables?

Comment: Could you provide us the code you are using?

Comment: @MarioLevrero: Done. See new edit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `<iron-meta>` does support binding to variables, but perhaps not in the way you think.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/QdNepDrg9b3eCTWF6oRO?p=preview

I looked through your code here, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31282947/polymer-1-0-data-binding-variable-to-iron-meta-element-value-attribute), and [here](https://github.com/veronicawwashington/polymer-sandbox/blob/master/app/elements/my-auth-toolbar/my-auth-toolbar.html) but I'm not entirely clear what your expectations are. Hopefully my attached repro might shed some light. I see you have declaratively bound `<iron-meta id="meta" key="route" xvalue="foo-bar" value="{{route}}"></iron-meta>` which is fine - when `route` changes, iron-meta's `key="route"` will update accordingly.

However, be aware that in Polymer 1.0, `<iron-meta>` is in essence a *one-way bind from parent to child* in the sense that you **set** a meta key value dynamically by binding to a property; but to **get** that value, you'll have to get it imperatively via iron-meta's `byKey()` method.

`<iron-meta>` is just a simple *monostate pattern* implementation without an in-built path notification mechanism. What this means is value **changes do not propagate upwards**. Therefore, doing something like

```
<!-- this does not work like the way you think -->
<iron-meta id="meta" key="foo" value="{{bar}}">
```

in order to *get* the value of `foo`, or *listen* to changes to `foo`, does not work. This behaves more like a *setter*, where you set the value of `foo` based on your data-bound property `bar`.

From what I gather, it seems that you're trying to implement some sort of global variable functionality. A monostate implementation used to work in Polymer 0.5, but not in 1.0. Unfortunately, until Google endorses a "best-practice" pattern for this, suggestions till-date seems a bit speculative to me. You might find this ([Polymer 1.0 Global Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849816/polymer-1-0-global-variables)) helpful.

Answer (score 4):

I have had success using `<iron-signals>` to communicate global information. I know there is a warning in the `<iron-signals>` documentation that discourages its use for related elements, but when broadcasting a shared resource it seems just the thing. For example:

```
// source element
var db = SomeDB.init();
this.fire('iron-signal', { name: 'database', data: db });

<-- sink element -->
<iron-signals on-iron-signal-database="dbChange"></iron-signals>

class SinkElement {
  dbChange(e, detail) {
    this.db = detail;
    this.db.getSomeData();
  }
}
```