# Persistent session variable in Polymer 1.0

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have two elements that are not directly connected (no host child relationship). I want to share some information between them as two-way data binding is not optimal. I thought about persistent session variables (like that exist in Meteor), is there is something like that in Polymer 1.0? If not, can somebody refer me to a viable solution.

**Edit:**

I just found out about [iron-signals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8) but the documentation states that it should be avoided, can somebody explain why it should be avoided? I would also appreciate it if somebody wrote an example of how to use it through an example.

**Edit:**

I discussed this question with the Polymer team in the Polymer Summit 2015. It was a part of a larger question, how to structure my app. They spoke in the summit about the mediator pattern. I recommend  watching the [talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZDjiUmx51y8) from the summit and visiting the [code in Github](https://github.com/kevinpschaaf/chat-view-paper).

Comment: https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-cookie/blob/master/polymer-cookie.html   cookie or a 'global' are worth look into

Comment: For some coded examples, you might want to check out this [Stack Overflow question and its answers][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849816/polymer-1-0-global-variables/31031678#31031678

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some coded examples using `<iron-signals>`, you might want to check out this [Stack Overflow question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849816/polymer-1-0-global-variables/31031678).

It's not as complicated as it first looks. [Study this documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) and [this demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-signals/blob/ee879a0bd3e972b8957c1735e094cb981774de4a/demo/index.html).

It's a simple two-step process:

1. Fire an `iron-signal` event like this:

   `this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'hello', data: 'kitty'});`
2. Listen for the `iron-signal` event with the same name (in this case, `hello`).
   Like this:

   `<iron-signals on-iron-signal-hello="doSomething"></iron-signals>`

Comment: It is a bit complicated, isn't it? I actually don't like the solutions posted in that link as there is a lot of coding involved just to achieve that simple behavior. There should be a simpler solution.

Comment: It's not as complicated as it looks. [Study this documentation](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-signals) and [this demo](https://github.com/PolymerElements/iron-signals/blob/ee879a0bd3e972b8957c1735e094cb981774de4a/demo/index.html). It's a simple two-step process. Step 1. Fire an `iron-signal` event like this: `this.fire('iron-signal', {name: 'hello', data: 'kitty'});`. Then, Step 2. Listen for the `iron-signal` event with the same name (in this case, `hello`). Like this: `<iron-signals on-iron-signal-hello="nowDoSomething"></iron-signals>` @SalahSaleh

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at iron-signals myself recently. It is useful for communication between loosely coupled distance components. It provides an "event bus" type functionality. I believe the warning you see in the iron-signals documentation (*"Note: avoid using iron-signals whenever you can use a controller (parent element) to mediate communication instead."*) is to prevent over-use in simple cases where ordinary Polymer property binding would do the job. In the context of the comment included in the iron-signals documentation, the parent element (the "controller") is the binding scope for the communicating child elements.

Also, iron-signals, has nothing to do with persistent session variables. Two separate issue there.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4Vu2yIaTSM#t=14m35s) (I linked to the exact minute and second where the concept is explained) which explains exactly the effect that I want. The Key difference between the answers posted by Mowzer is that you wrap the whole of your application in a template and access the attributes through observers which is a much easier concept once you get it. 
I think the video is straight forward to understand, so I will not go to much explanations here.

Answer (score 1):

In addition, [here is another related question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31339287/polymer-1-0-does-iron-meta-support-binding-to-dynamic-variables/) with working code examples. Only they refer to `<iron-meta>` and `<iron-local-storage>`.